# Is there any consideration while comparing Enums in LINQ-to-NHibernate or LINQ?

Tags: c#, linq, nhibernate, linq-to-nhibernate

In such a query:

```
var q = from l in session.Linq<Letter>()
    where
    letterTypeSearch == null ? true : 
        (l.LetterType.ToString() == letterTypeSearch)
```

l.LetterType is an Enum.

**UPDATE**
It seems that's impossible to compare Enums in current linq-to-nhibernate. While letterTypeSearch is a string containing a `LetterType` instance that is `ToString()`ed and `LetterType` is inherited from `int`, there 3 ways of comparisons:

1- Comparing in `String`: It impossible because `l.LetterType.ToString()` produces "(ArgumentOutOfRangeException): Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.
Parameter name: index, " error.

2- Comparing in `Enum` (`LetterType`) itself: It is impossible too because `l.LetterType == LetterType.Internal` results in "(QueryException): Type mismatch in NHibernate.Criterion.SimpleExpression: LetterType expected type System.Int32, actual type Faraconesh.EnterpriseAppUnits.OfficeAutomation.BusinessEntities.LetterType, 
" error.

3- Comparing in `Int32`: Yet not possible, because `Convert.ToInt32(l.LetterType)` generates "(NotImplementedException): The method ToInt32 is not implemented., " error.

So how can I compare Enums in LINQ-to-NHibernate? Is this problem specific to LINQ-to-NHibernate or all LINQ users have such a problem?

**UPDATE2**
here are class, enum and mapping (smmarized):

```
    public class Letter
    {
        private LetterType _letterType;
        public LetterType LetterType
        {
            set
            {
                _letterType = value;
            }//end  
            get
            {
                return _letterType;
            }//end  
        }
}
```

=========

public enum LetterType
{
    Incoming = 0,
    Outgoing = 1,
    Internal = 2,
}

=========

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<hibernate-mapping xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2" default-lazy="false">
  <class
       name="Faraconesh.EnterpriseAppUnits.OfficeAutomation.BusinessEntities.Letter,Faraconesh.EnterpriseAppUnits.OfficeAutomation.BusinessEntities"
        table="OfficeAutomation_Letter">

    <property
         name="LetterType" column="LetterType"
         type="int" update="true" insert="true" access="property"
         not-null="true"/>

  </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

Comment: You are not using the latest Linq provider.  The latest Linq provider is available in the NHibernate trunk.

Comment: @Michael: I'm using NHibernate 2.1.2.4000 and NHibernate.Linq 1.1.0.1001, is there any problem with them?

Comment: There are two NH Linq providers.  One from NHContrib, which is what you are using and one from the NHibernate trunk, which you are not using.  Your question says "current linq-to-nhibernate", but you are not using the current Linq provider, you are using the older one.  My comment was just attempting to clarify that for you.

Comment: @Michael, tnks for ur kind replies I'm using this: http://sourceforge.net/projects/nhibernate/files/NHibernate/2.1.2GA/NHibernate.Linq-2.1.2-GA-Bin.zip/download Is it the REAL latest version? If not, would you please provide the correct one? Because I'm confused with this.

Comment: NHibernate 2.1.2 is the most recent official release version.  It is not the most current version.  The current version used to be relatively easily available via HornGet, but that is down at the moment, so you'd have to get it from SVN, which is not as convenient: https://nhibernate.svn.sourceforge.net/svnroot/nhibernate/trunk/

Comment: @Michael: Thanking for your comments, I'm using just those mentioned assemblies (2.1.2 and 1.1.0) and never used trunk but answer provided by Lachlan solved my problem.

Comment: The HornGet website is back up.  You can get binaries for the NHibernate trunk (which includes the latest NHibernate Linq provider) here: http://www.hornget.net/packages/orm/nhibernate/nhibernate-trunk

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have mapped the enum as `type="int"` which causes the error, probably because there are no implicit conversions to and from int. If you drop the type attribute, the enum will be mapped to an int value in the database and the Linq queries will work.

Note also that in your property mapping every attribute except name and type are unnecessary as they specify the default values. "Name" is the only required attribute on a property mapping, see section [property](http://nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/index.html#mapping-declaration-property) in the reference documentation.

```
<property name="LetterType" />
```

Using the latest (2.1.2GA) version of NHibernate.Linq, which is available from the **NHibernate Core** download link on [nhforge.org](http://nhforge.org), the following queries with enums work as expected.

```
var q = from l in session.Linq<Letter>()
    where l. LetterType == LetterType.A4
    select l;
var result = q.ToList<Letter>();

LetterType? ltype = LetterType.A4;
q = from l in session.Linq<Letter>()
    select l;
if (code != null) {
    q = q.Where( l => l.LetterType == ltype.Value );
}
result = q.ToList<Letter>();
```

However, this form of the last query will not work if ltype is null as the query parser will still try to use ltype.Value.

```
q = from l in session.Linq<Letter>()
    where ltype != null && l => l.LetterType == ltype.Value
    select l;
result = q.ToList<Letter>();
```

Comment: @Lachlan, I'm afraid it may be because of way the Enum is mapped. Mine is using:     <property
         name="LetterType" column="LetterType"
         type="int" update="true" insert="true" access="property"
         not-null="true"
              
        />
May be this the cause of the problem?

Comment: @afsharm Can you add your mapping with type=int to the question.

Comment: @Lachlan: Many thanks for your solution, you really saved me from nightmares! But have one more question: I dropped `type="int"` and everything went O.K. But I thought `type` attribute was mandatory, wasn't it?

Answer (score 0):

If I were you, I create a Dot net Enum with these nhibernate Enum and then compare them with dot net equals.

Comment: What do you mean by nhibernate enum? There is just one enum and that is dotnet Enum.

Comment: @Afshar, As I underestandyour question, You want to compare an Enum with a Nhibernate Result. and I suggest you to store NHibernate result to a standard .net Enum and then compare these 2 enums together.